# MySQL - Got error 28 from storage engine while importing large database file

Tags: mysql, mamp-pro

I am importing a large .sql file and have increased myisam_sort_buffer_size optimally.

Everything ran smooth but hit a wall once I ran out of storage on my disk.

Is there a way to finish the import and skip what already exists once space is cleared?

Answer (score 0):

Try mysqlimport -i dbname fileToImport